# Are PowerMac G5 GPU compatible with ATX PC's

Tags: gpu, power-mac

I would like to know if the Nvidia GPU's from the old PowerMac G5 are compatible with other PC's as well. This question also broadly asks if the pci express slots for both powerpc based processors and intel processors have similar fetch and decode protocols.

Comment: yes… & no… Power Macs had 3 PCI types across the years, PCI, PCI-X and PCI Express & some of them had AGP graphics. If it fits, it might work, or it might not.

Comment: The other issue would be… how much use would it possibly be in this day & age? Rough speed values - modern high-end GPU, score 20,000. G5 GeForce FX 5200, score… 20.

Comment: @Tetsujin well I am only interested in having a visual interface to simply display stuff on the screen and not do any graphic intensive work. So its better to reuse and recycle items instead of discarding so I am quite interested to know if it can be recycled.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is it possible to know what PCI type the GPU is by just looking at the card slots on the GPU. I am not familiar with AGP graphics.

Comment: You could try googling images of the card types. I don't remember how much they differed, it's too long ago to remember, I'm afraid. I went from an AGP G4 to PCI-e Mac Pro, so I never really worked with the intermediate stages. It must be said, though, that it will probably burn more power for significantly less result than a modern card you could buy 2nd hand for 10 bucks.